# Proving that a successful search of hash function is $\Theta(1+\alpha)$

Tags: algorithms, hash

**Question**: Prove that successful search of hash function with chaining (list at each slot) takes $\Theta(1+\alpha)$.

Given a dictionary or hash table that has a chain at each slot in case we have a collision. So, given that the load factor of table $\alpha = \frac{n}{m}$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the hash table and $m$ is the number of slots. We can see that successfully searching for item takes $\Theta(1+\alpha)$.

**Solution**: The answer I got did the following (Courtesy to Introduction to Algorithms book):

The expected number of elements examined during a successful search is $1$ more than the number of elements examined when the sought for element was inserted (since every new element goes at the end of the list). To find the expected number of elements examined, we therefore take the average, over the $n$ items in the table, of $1$ plus the expected length of the list to which the $i$th element is added. The expected length of that list is $\frac{i-1}{m}$, and so the expected number of elements examined in a successful search is

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1+\frac{i-1}{m}) = 1 + \frac{1}{nm}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)$$

$$...$$

**Problem**: how we got $\frac{1}{n}$ in front of the sum please in $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1+\frac{i-1}{m})$? This is my problem not the solution of the question.

Comment: are you familiar with the term *expected value* (from a probability course)?

Comment: @nirshahar. Thanks for the reply. Yes please.

Comment: Then this $\frac{1}{n}$ is there because they calculated the expected value of the number of slots we need to search. The $\frac{1}{n}$ is therefore there because we are averaging over the $n$ items.

Comment: @nirshahar. So basically it comes from $Pr(x)$  in $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_iPr\left( x_i \right)}$ please?

Comment: Yes precisely. But the distribution is uniform so all $Pr(x_i)$ are $\frac{1}{n}$. Basically, its just a regular old average.

Comment: @nirshahar. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nirshahar. Do you have any idea please why we have $1+$ above in the sum?

Comment: You took it outside the average: averaging a lot of $1$s will still be a $1$. Or simply, because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \frac{1}{n} n = 1$

Comment: @nirshahar. Thanks. I don't mean this please, but what I meant is based on the question, it was mentioned, "we therefore take the average, over the n items in the table, of 1 plus the expected length of the list to which the ith element is added.", so can you please explain what 1 is there in to$∑(1+(i−1)/m)$?

Comment: Oh, this is because you have to do at least one more operation each time *after* you find where it should be. Or, you can also think of it as "insurance" that we still do operations even when the list is empty. This $1$ there just means you anyways do some computation except finding whatever you wanted to

Comment: So $ 1$ is basically finding the slot of there the item is please (is this what you mean by doing extra operation after we locate the item)? If that is the case, then $(1+0)$ when we have only one item in the hash table, so we did not do one extra operation after we found it here? This is how I understand it, but I am not sure.